# Matching regex groups within groups if they exist in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have these couple lines that I would like to match and right now I use multiple regexes to match them all, however I'm wondering if it is possible to match both in one regex:

```
@@Author:logan
//and these, three variations
@@tags:markdown,github,repetitivetag, tagwithsubtags:subtag, another:subtag:subtag2:repeating:this:repeating,repetitivetag,repetitivetag:withsubby,repetitivetag:withsubtag
@@tags:markdown;github;repetitivetag;tagwithsubtags:subtag,another:subtag:subtag2:repeating:this:repeating;repetitivetag;repetitivetag:withsubby;repetitivetag:withsubtag
@@tags:markdown;git-hub;repetitive-tag;tag_with_sub-tags:sub_tag,another:sub_tag:sub-tag2:repeating:this:repeat-_-_-ing;repetitive-tag;repetitive_tag:with_subby;repetitive_tag:with_subtag
```

What I do first is to match the `@@NAME:VALUE` part:

- `/^(?:@@)(\w+):(.*.)(?:\n+|$)/gm`

let's say the first group is `NAME` and second group is `VALUE`.

If `NAME` is `tags` then I match the following regex in `VALUE`:

- `/(\w+)((?=,|;)|(:\w[\w|\-]+\w){0,}|)/g`

This matches several groups that are like `TAG;TAG;TAG ...` or `TAG,TAG,TAG ...` in `VALUE` that we matched before

Then I match each `TAG` with this to get the `SUBTAG`

- `/(:)(\w[\w|\-]+\w)(?=:|)/g`

Now that matches groups like `:SUBTAG:SUBTAG:SUBTAG ...` within `TAG` that we matched above

## In Summary

I want to match

- `(@@)(NAME)(:)(VALUE)`

  - `(TAG)(;)(TAG)(;)(TAG) ...` in VALUE

    - `(:)(SUBTAG)(:)(SUBTAG))(;)` in tag

### example

1. `@@Author:logan` should be able to get `Name = Author`, `Value = logan`
2. if value is multiple, like if its seperated by comma or semi-colon then matching something like `@@tags:tag1;tag2` should be able to get

   `Name = Tags`, `Value = ['tag1','tag2']
3. if value has a subvalue such as

   `@@Author:logan:lastname`

   or this as its intended purpose

   `@@Tags:tag1:subtag;tag2:subtag1:subtag2` should be able to get:

   `Name = Author`, `Value = [{logan : [lastname]}]` and

   `Name = Tags`, `Value = [{tag1 : [subtag]}, {tag2 : [subtag1, subtag2]}]`

How can I match groups within groups and only if they exist?

Comment: Using one regex only would lead to an unmaintainable monster imho... By the way, `,|;` can be replaced with `[,;]`

Comment: ah thanks, initially I'm writing a ace highlighter for this so that's why I was wondering if I could use a one liner. So for these purposes it is more common to capture groups then process that group and so on? Am I on the right track?

Comment: I don't know whether this is more common, however it will certainly be easier :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This gives exactly the output you want:

```
// Examples:
var a='@@Author:logan';
var b='@@tags:tag1;tag2';
var c='@@Author:logan:lastname';
var d='@@Tags:tag1;tag2:subtag1:subtag2';
var hard1='@@tags:markdown,github,repetitivetag, tagwithsubtags:subtag, another:subtag:subtag2:repeating:this:repeating,repetitivetag,repetitivetag:withsubby,repetitivetag:withsubtag';
var hard2='@@tags:markdown;github;repetitivetag;tagwithsubtags:subtag,another:subtag:subtag2:repeating:this:repeating;repetitivetag;repetitivetag:withsubby;repetitivetag:withsubtag';
var hard3='@@tags:markdown;git-hub;repetitive-tag;tag_with_sub-tags:sub_tag,another:sub_tag:sub-tag2:repeating:this:repeat-_-_-ing;repetitive-tag;repetitive_tag:with_subby;repetitive_tag:with_subtag';

function tags(a){
    // Gets the name:
    var name=a.match(/^@@.*?(:|.$)/);
    if(!name) return;
    var temp=a.indexOf(':')+1;
    name=name[0].substring(2).replace(':','');
    // Returns the name if thats all there is:
    if(!temp) return name;
    a=a.substring(temp);
    // Gets the value:
    var value=a.split(/[,;]/);
    if(value.length==1&&value[0].indexOf(':')==-1)
        value=value[0];
    else for(var i=0;i<value.length;i++) if(value[i].indexOf(':')!=-1) {
        // Gets the subtags if they exist:
        temp={};
        a=value[i].split(':');
        // .shift() will remove/return the first of the array
        temp[a.shift()]=a;
        value[i]=temp;
    }
    return {name:name,value:value};
}
console.log([tags(a),tags(b),tags(c),tags(d),tags(hard1),tags(hard2),tags(hard3)]);
```

This was really cool to code for actually. I'm not sure if your question said exactly what you wanted, but if it didn't, then everything should be really easy to modify. Hope you like the else-for-if statement!

Comment: I'm glad you had fun coding it :) Thank you for your answer, it is good to know another alternative approach to this. As my purpose lies towards writing a syntax highlighter for ace I cannot use this as a whole but would have to break this apart into three part rule. However it is good to know another way of doing this that may help me break it down better :)

Comment: Do you just want the name and value parts separated? Or do you want name, tags, and subtag parts separated?

And just to get it straight, the value is representative of tags and subtags altogether, right?

Comment: Well, to clear it up, the results in your code are exactly how I wanted them to be parsed. The problem is when writing syntax highlighter for ace [with this tool](http://ace.ajax.org/tool/mode_creator.html) I need to chain them somehow in a clever manner so that it should look for `@@key:value` then if there is a `value:subvalue` then it should highlight subvalue, then if there is another value like in `@@key:value:subvalue;anothervalue:anothersubvalue` then it should get the other value and so on... What you did is just a different color of what I do to parse it :)

Comment: It didn't fit in one comment... Well my question was if there was a way to capture groups within groups in just one regex. Just pretend that these are all regexes: `(@@ part)(:)(key)(if there is :\w+ then (:)(value part))` and so on... I guess the problem is that captured array size would be dynamic... Anyways here is the gist that shows how to test it https://gist.github.com/4527881

Comment: Yeah I didn't quite have time to figure out another solution... Though I do understand the problem more now.